# Using sabre/dav server with floccus

Tags: php, webdav, self-hosting, sabredav

[EDIT 2]: TL;DR - floccus can't use Digest Authorization, which was how my sabre/dav server was set up. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/marcelklehr/floccus/issues/289).

---

I've set up a sabre/dav server on a Raspberry Pi 4 by following the instructions [here](https://sabre.io/dav/gettingstarted/). When I navigate to my server URL in my browser, I get to the sabre web interface. I can upload files here, and they appear in my `public` folder.

Now, I'm trying to set up [floccus](https://floccus.org/) to sync my bookmarks with the server, but I'm hitting a wall. I put in my server URL and credentials just as if I were connecting through my browser, and I specify the path where the bookmarks file should be stored. I save those settings, then click 'Sync Now', but I end up with an error: `E018: Couldn't authenticate with the server.` There's a button beside the error to download a debug log, but it's an empty file.

[image: Server details]

[image: Error message]

I've tried various ways of setting the path - a file at the root of my `public` folder (`bookmarks.xbel`), a file in a directory further down (`bookmarks/bookmarks.xbel`), both with and without the file created first, and all of these result in the same error.

Has anyone had any luck with this before that might be able to shine a light on what I'm doing wrong here?

[EDIT]: Using @Marcel Klehr's answer, I managed to track down the response being sent by the server when I try to sync:

```
<d:error xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns">
  <s:sabredav-version>3.2.2</s:sabredav-version>
  <s:exception>Sabre\DAV\Exception\NotAuthenticated</s:exception>
  <s:message>No 'Authorization: Digest' header found. Either the client didn't send one, or the server is misconfigured</s:message>
</d:error>
```

And these are the headers:

[image: Request/response headers]

Looks like floccus is using Basic Authorization instead of Digest. I can see in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/marcelklehr/floccus/issues/289) that Digest is not supported by floccus. I'll try reconfiguring the server to use Basic, and see if that fixes it.

[EDIT 2]: Switching to Basic Authorization fixed the issue. I've marked @Marcel's answer as the Accepted answer, since their guidance helped me track down what was wrong.

Comment: Can you open the sabredav endpoint in your browser? If you can open it directly it's often a good indicator it's setup correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug network requests of the extension as follows:

Firefox

- Go to `about:debugging` -> `This firefox`
- click on `inspect` button next to floccus entry
- go to the network tab in the inspector tab
- trigger a sync by clicking on `sync now` for the account of your choice.
- check the failing network requests

Chrome

- Go to `chrome://extensions`
- enable `Developer mode`
- click on `dist/html/background.html` button in floccus' entry next to "Inspect views: "
- go to the network tab in the inspector window
- trigger a sync by clicking on `sync now` for the account of your choice
- check the failing network requests

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. This helped me cop the fact that floccus doesn't support Digest Authorization. When I switched to Basic, it worked right away. Any update on adding Digest support to floccus?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your actual issue isn't with the path itself but with the server (just look at the error).

Have you tried removing the right-most slash?

In other words, replace `http://my-public-ip/sabre/server.php/` with `http://my-public-ip/sabre/server.php`.